# Using jade template for both inserts and updates?

Tags: node.js, pug

I have a jade template that I would like to use for both inserts and updates of records.  In order to accomodate updates I have setup my template like below:

```
label(for="title") Title
input.col-sm-10.form-control#title(type="text",placeholder="Enter title...", value=data.title)
```

Which works great for updates.  But if I'm creating a new record then `data` is null and the template errors out when trying to load.  In order to get around this I have been using the following method:

```
label(for="title") Title
input.col-sm-10.form-control#title(type="text",placeholder="Enter title...", value= typeof data === 'undefined' || data === null ? "" : data.title)
```

Which works but seems very verbose.  Is there a better method for handling this or do I need to add a ternary if statement if I want to use this view for both inserts and updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make this a bit less verbose by using the `||` trick twice.

```
value= ( (data || {}).title || "" )
```